# create a countdown clock

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create a countdown watch that displays in days,hours,minutes and seconds the time LEFT before for example 14 August 2017 I have this code to show real time(hope it helps other people) but I don't know how to edit it for what I want.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
tday=new Array("Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday");
tmonth=new Array("January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December");

function GetClock(){
var d=new Date();
var nday=d.getDay(),nmonth=d.getMonth(),ndate=d.getDate(),nyear=d.getYear();
if(nyear<1000) nyear+=1900;
var nhour=d.getHours(),nmin=d.getMinutes(),nsec=d.getSeconds(),ap;

if(nhour==0){ap=" AM";nhour=12;}
else if(nhour<12){ap=" AM";}
else if(nhour==12){ap=" PM";}
else if(nhour>12){ap=" PM";nhour-=12;}

if(nmin<=9) nmin="0"+nmin;
if(nsec<=9) nsec="0"+nsec;

document.getElementById('clockbox').innerHTML=""+tday[nday]+", "+tmonth[nmonth]+" "+ndate+", "+nyear+" "+nhour+":"+nmin+":"+nsec+ap+"";
}

window.onload=function(){
GetClock();
setInterval(GetClock,1000);
}
</script>
<div id="clockbox"></div>
```

I googled it but all I got were jquery plugins,I am all for jquery but I don't want no stupid plugins.Also once the set date has come i would like it to show 00 : 00 : 00 : 00 (or some other alternative like make counter disappear) until I edit it for next year.Any help much apreeciated.thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I used this just yesterday:

https://www.sitepoint.com/build-javascript-countdown-timer-no-dependencies/

I made some modifications because I had to used it with timestamps:

```
var currentTime = {
    days: 0,
    hours: 0,
    minutes: 0,
    seconds: 0
};
var sending = false;
var $clockDays = $('.coupon-wrapper .clock-days');
var $clockHours = $('.coupon-wrapper .clock-hours');
var $clockMinutes = $('.coupon-wrapper .clock-minutes');
var $clockSeconds = $('.coupon-wrapper .clock-seconds');
var dataNow = $('.coupon-wrapper .cupon-time-value').attr('data-now');
var dataEndLine = $('.coupon-wrapper .cupon-time-value').attr('data-endline');
var countDownClock = {
    firstRun: true,
    getTimeRemaining: function (startTime, endTime){
        var t = endTime - startTime;
        var seconds = Math.floor( (t/1000) % 60 );
        var minutes = Math.floor( (t/1000/60) % 60 );
        var hours = Math.floor( (t/(1000*60*60)) % 24 );
        var days = Math.floor( t/(1000*60*60*24) );
        return {
            'total': t,
            'days': days,
            'hours': hours,
            'minutes': minutes,
            'seconds': seconds
        };
    },
    initializeClock: function(startTime, endTime){
        start = new Date(startTime * 1000);
        end = new Date(endTime * 1000);
        var timeinterval = setInterval(function(){
            var t = {};
            start.setSeconds(start.getSeconds() + 1);
            t = countDownClock.getTimeRemaining(start, end);
            if (countDownClock.isDifferentFromTheLastComparison(currentTime.days, t.days)) {
                $clockDays.text(t.days);
                currentTime.days = t.days;
            }
            if (countDownClock.isDifferentFromTheLastComparison(currentTime.hours, t.hours)) {
                $clockHours.text(('0' + t.hours).slice(-2));
                currentTime.hours = t.hours;
            }
            if (countDownClock.isDifferentFromTheLastComparison(currentTime.minutes, t.minutes)) {
                $clockMinutes.text(('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2));
                currentTime.minutes = t.minutes;
            }
            $clockSeconds.text(('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2));
            currentTime.seconds = t.seconds;
            if (countDownClock.firstRun) {
                countDownClock.firstRun = false;
                $('.coupon-wrapper .coupon-time-wrapper').fadeIn(200);
            }
            if(t.total <= 0){
                clearInterval(timeinterval);
            }
        },1000);
    },
    isDifferentFromTheLastComparison: function(currentValue, newValue) {
        if (currentValue != newValue) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};
countDownClock.initializeClock(dataNow, dataEndLine);
```

IMPORTANT: The clock div wrapper is display:none when page loads.

Comment: i cant get it to work.i am very new to javascript.please Mr SebCar i would very much appreciate if you could share a jsfiddle

Comment: Make a new js fiddle and share it, we'll help you.